# Wordpress Bootstrap Caret as Dropdown Toggle on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, hover, caret

I've been doing a lot of research on this topic and have found quite a few similar answers/solutions to this, but nothing for my situation specifically.

Here is my development server: http://blmprinthouse.com/summit_sustainability/

I have Bootstrap integrated into my Wordpress navigation. I have modified the Bootstrap files so that on desktop (anything over 776px wide), the dropdowns appear on hover. Also, I've enabled top-level links to bring you to actual pages rather than displaying the dropdowns like normal. Long-story shorts, it works perfect above 776px.

Which brings us to mobile/tablet. I am trying to keep the top-level links clickable links, while the carets themselves, when clicked, ideally will drop the menu down below. I've seen this mentioned as a UI/UX conundrum, and I can see this point, but I have made the carets larger and right aligned them to ease the UX.

Within my wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php, I have found a way to separate the top-level links and the caret links, but that's as far as I have gotten, since clicking the caret does nothing. This is done by changing this line:

```
$item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? '<span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
```

To this:

```
$item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? '</a><a class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
```

I've removed this ^ for the time being since it causes a few alignment issues, but if anyone has any ideas as to how I can make the carets clickable to display the dropdowns for their respective menu items that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Bump.  Anyone know how the make the caret toggle the respective dropdown on mobile?

Comment: Bump. Anyone have any insight here?

Comment: Bump. Caret to display bootstrap dropdown on mobile. Link still clickable. Thoughts?